# If item already in Database, do different ActionResult in View - ASP.NET MVC4 EF5 HTML5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, view, entity-framework-5

Say if im about to go to a simple Index() view for "Item".
I have an action result in that index view which adds to the database (which would be a customer which has a library of items in the model). If the customer already has that chosen item in the database, I would like the ActionLink to show something like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove from Library", "RemoveFromLibrary", new {id=item.Id})
```

Customer Model

```
public List<LoanedItem> Library { get; set; }
```

Item Index View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add To Library", "AddToItems", new {id=item.Id})
```

How would I go about this in the simplest possibile way? (am new to this)

Thank you

**PS. In a realistic scenario, its like an ebay watchlist. If an item is already in the watchlist, show text to remove from watch list for that item**

EDIT:

Im not sure whether to write code in Controller or the view itself but for the view, I tried adding the below and got stuck

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Customer c = (Customer)Session["customer"];
        var items = ItemRepository.GetItems().OfType<Item>();
        var itemsLoanedToCustomer = customerRepository.GetItems(c.Id);
        foreach (Item i in items)
        {
            if (itemsLoanedToCustomer.Contains(i))
            {

            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

FULL Index() View

```
    @model IEnumerable<MMC.Model.Item>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Tracks</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Artist)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DailyLoanPrice)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Publisher)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.YearOfPublication)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Artist)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DailyLoanPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Publisher)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.YearOfPublication)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Add To Library", "AddToTracks", new {id=item.Id})

        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Customer Model

```
    public class Customer
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ForeName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public List<LoanedItem> MediaLibrary { get; set; }
    public Bill balance { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        if (Library == null)
        {
            Library = new List<LoanedItem>();
        }
    }
}
```

Item Model

```
    public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double DailyLoanPrice { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime LastTimeBorrowed { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfTimeBorrowed { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    //rating
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double TotalSalesIncome { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublication { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If they already have it, remove it and add it again? Your question is not clear. What code have you tried?

Comment: @SamLeach please see above

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the list of LibraryItems to display action links for? If they are in your model then;

In the view check if the user already has the item and display the action link accordingly.

```
@(if(Model.Customers.Items.Select(x => x.Id).Intersect(Model.Items.Select(x => x.Id)).Any())
{
    Html.ActionLink("Remove from Library", "RemoveFromLibrary", new {id=item.Id});
}
else
{
    Html.ActionLink("Add To Library", "AddToItems", new {id=item.Id});
})
```

Further, if you are using EF you could do something like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Customer c = (Customer)Session["customer"];

    // Items is the navigation property.
    var customerItems = customerRepository.GetItems(c.Id).Items;

    return View();
}
```

Use the following ViewModel

```
public class CustomerItem
{
    public List<Item> Items;
    public List<Customer> Customers;

    public CustomerItem()
    {
        Items = new List<Items>();
        Customers = new List<Items>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this view is strongly typed and is strongly typed to "Item" so cant get at the library items that way in the view. The library items for each customer is in the customerRepository not the trackrepository. This view contains ALL items that are in the catalog of items available. The customer only has a few of them which is stored in their personal library in the customer model. Essentially what I need is like the functionality of an ebay watchlist. If the item already in the watchlist, then show remove from watchlist

Comment: how do I use your addition in the view example?

Comment: Post your full View and all used Models and I can help you.

Comment: added, look in original post

Comment: You need to change your View Model to include both Customer and Item.